# Laravel: browse to phpmyadmin in Homestead Vagrant box

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, vagrant, homestead

I just installed Homestead / Vagrant box for a project. I was able to set it up and now I can see the page of the Laravel project in the browser.
I am used to MAMP so the servers are there and I can just browse to `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/` but how can I access it in the virtual machine? where are the settings to be made for port forwarding etc?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on MacOS you're better off using Sequel Pro. It's a free app to connect to MySQL servers.

You can connect to homestead by using the following settings:

Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 33060
User: homestead
Pass: secret

Comment: You may get some heat from this, but I agree that this answers the question, although perhaps not the way OP wanted. A client like Sequel Pro is more powerful, faster, easier to configure, and overall better than phpMyAdmin, especially when doing local dev.

Comment: I already installed phpmyadmin in vagrant and I'm now able to browse to the page from the host. Thanks